# gRPC Server-Side Streaming: How to Continue Stream Indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

I am having an issue with a lightweight gRPC server I'm writing in NodeJS. I'm referencing the documentation [here](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node/). I have been able to compile my proto files representing messages and services, and have successfully stood up a gRPC server with a server-side stream method I am able to trigger via [BloomRPC](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc).

I have a proto message called `parcel`, which has one field: `parcel_id`. I want this method to stream a parcel of data every second. My first rudimentary pass at this was a loop that executes every second for a minute, and applies a new parcel via `call.write(parcel)`. I've included the method below, it executes with no errors when I invoke it via gRPC.

```
/**
 * Implements the updateParcel RPC method.
 * Feeds new parcel to the passed in "call" param
 * until the simulation is stopped.
 */
function updateParcels(call) {
  console.log("Parcels requested...");

  // Continuously stream parcel protos to requester
  let i = 0;
  let id = 0;
  while(i < 60){
    // Create dummy parcel
    let parcel = new messages.Parcel();
    parcel.setParcelId(id);
    id++;// Increment id

    // Write parcel to call object
    console.log("Sending parcel...");
    call.write(parcel);

    // Sleep for a second (1000 millis) before repeating
    sleep(1000);
  }
  call.end();
}
```

My issue is that, although I am able to call my methods and receive results, the behavior is that I receive the first result *immediately* on the client (for both NodeJS client code *and* BloomRPC calls), but receive the last 59 results *all at once* only after the server executes `call.end()`. There are no errors, and the parcel objects I receive on the client are accurate and formatted correctly, they are just batched as described.

**How can I achieve a constant stream of my parcels in real time? Is this possible? I've looked but can't tell for sure - do gRPC server-side streams have a batching behavior by default?** I've tried my best to understand the gRPC documentation, but I can't tell if I'm simply trying to force gRPC server-side streams to do something they weren't designed to do. Thanks for any help, and let me know if I can provide any more information, as this is my first gRPC related SO question and I may have missed some relevant information.

Comment: It could be unrelated to gRPC, what's your `sleep` implementation there? the default one provided by node is a promise, so you probably have to declare the function as `async` and call `await sleep(1000)` for this to work.

Comment: @mrbm that's EXACTLY what it was. Very glad you pointed this out. I was just using a sleep function from another javascript project's utility folder - didn't happen to work in this case. Totally solved after taking your suggestion.

Comment: @mrbm If you post that comment as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be unrelated to gRPC, but to the `sleep` implementation used there.

The default one provided by node is a promise, so for this to work you probably have to declare the function as `async` and call `await sleep(1000);`.